# Changing return (callback) result for mongodb remove function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback, return-value

I'm working on a room booking project. In essence there are users, and bookings. A user can have one booking, as can a booking be owned by one user.

When I delete a booking I also need to update the reference in the user object.

```
apiRouter.route('/bookings/:id')
    .delete(function(req, res){
        Booking.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, user) {
            if (err) res.send(err);

            // Do stuff ... then return a message
            res.json({ message: 'The booking was thrown towards a singularity.'});
        });
    }
);
```

As you can see I want the callback to give me the user object that is stored with the booking object, as per my schema:

```
var BookingSchema = new Schema({
    user: {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User' , required: true},
    room: {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Room' , required: true},
    equipment: [{type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Equipment' }],
    startDate: {type: Date, required: true},
    endDate:  {type: Date, required: true}
});
```

According to the mongodb docs, versions 2.6+ return a `WriteResult`

> **Successful Results**
>
> The `remove()` returns a `WriteResult` object that contains the status of the operation. Upon success, the `WriteResult` object contains information on the number of documents removed:
>
> `WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 4 })`
>
> *http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/*

So right now in the `user` variable in my callback I am getting the number of documents that were removed by invoking `.remove()`. Is there anyway for me to override this behaviour *only* for the removal of `booking` objects? Otherwise I can save the `user._id` to scope before the deletion occurs, and perform another query to get the user object. Just curious if this is possible. Thanks!